# Why is my struct constructor, which contains other structs, not working?

Tags: c++, struct, constructor, physics

I'm trying to create a basic physics' simulation that calculates rectilinear movement.
When I tried to add a constructor to the *Body* struct, it showed the following error:

> no matching function to call to 'Vector::Vector()'

Here's the code:

```
struct Point{
    int x,y;
    Point(int _x, int _y) : x(_x), y(_y)
    {
    }
};
struct Vector{
    int value, direction;
    Vector(int _value, int _direction) : value(_value), direction(_direction)
    {

    }
};
struct Body{
    std::string ID;
    int m;
    Vector v, a;
    Point pos;

    Body(std::string _ID = "NONE", int _m = 0, Point _pos = Point(0, 0))
    {
        ID = _ID;
        m = _m;
        pos = _pos;
        v = Vector(0, 0);
        a = Vector(0, 0);
    }
};
```

I don't have the slightest idea why this is happening.
I just figured out if I declare *pos* before *v* and *a*, the error replaces 'Vector' with 'Point'. Also, the constructor works perfectly without declaring any of those variables.
It's probably a very dumb overlook. Help.

Comment: Your `Body` constructor should also use member initializer list syntax, the same way that your `Point` and `Vector` do. That will fix the error

Comment: You could also give Vector a default constructor if that's a valid use case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Members are initialized before the constructor body is executed. Hence, the constructor body is the wrong place to initialize members. Use the member initialization list instead:

```
Body(std::string _ID = "NONE", int _m = 0, Point _pos = Point(0, 0))
: ID(_ID), m(_m), v(0,0), a(0,0), pos(_pos) {
}
```

In your code, because you did not specify an initializer for the members, they were default initialized before the constructor body runs. But `Vector` has no default constructor.

Note that members are initialized in the order they are listed in the class. Typically compilers warn when the order in the initializer list is different.

Comment: `v(Vector(0,0)), a(Vector(0,0))` can be simplified to `v(0,0), a(0,0)`

Answer (score 0):

Both things, writing a default constructor for structs `Vector` and `Point`, and writing the `Body` constructor as a member initializer list, worked individually and together.
Thanks a lot.